# Using JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTIONS

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Here's my problem, I'm trying to get this bit of code to work so that in my GUI, when I click on yes, the product is added (that bit of code is still to be developed) and the `addproductwindow` closes, but when no is clicked the `JOptionPane` closes, but the add product window remains open.
(the `System.out.print(" no ");`) was me just testing what came out from the inputs.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Do you want to add Product: ","Confirmation",dialogButton);

   if (dialogButton == 1){
       System.out.println(" no ");

    } else { 
      addProductWindow.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution 
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Do you want to add Product: ","Confirmation",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                  
                 if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                   addProductWindow.dispose();                   
                  
seemed to do it

Answer (score 1):

When using `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (...)` you need to check which button was clicked by the user.

The basic code is:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (...);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    //  do something
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use Dialogs for more information and working examples.

```
if (dialogButton == 1)
```

Don't use "magic numbers". Nobody knows what "1" means. The API will have variable for you do use that are more descriptive.

Comment: thank you i think i was trying 1, 0  etc cause for some reason i thought my friend said thats how the YES_NO worked.

Answer (score 1):

For `addProductWindow` to close, you have to call `addProductWindow.dispose()` method in the if block too.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to add Product: ", "Confirmation", dialogButton);

    if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        addProductWindow.dispose();       // you forgot this
    } else {
        System.out.println(" no ");
        addProductWindow.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you :) will remove the addProductWindow.dispose() on the else part though as want to keep the other window open in that case :) much appreciated